Limiting voltage on voltage monitoring pin
Question:
How do I limit the voltage on a voltage monitoring pin to 28 V DC (due to voltage rating) when the power rail voltage to be measured may go up to 48 V DC continuous?
Are there DC-DC converter solutions where the output follows the input to 28 V and after this the output is regulated?
Context:
I am using the HUSB238A USB Power Delivery IC (PD Sink Controller). It can theoretically negotiate up to 48 V on the power rail but it's voltage monitoring pin is only rated to around 28 V...
Of course, I want to get an accurate measurement up to around 28 V, but then the voltage on the voltage monitoring pin needs to stay between 24 V and 28 V in order not trigger a low voltage error, nor damage the IC.
The datasheet suggests putting a DC-DC converter between the power rail and the voltage monitoring pin for this situation but gives no further information. I am not exactly sure how this is supposed to work exactly while allowing for accurate measurements up to 28 V.
VBUS pin (in diagram) is the pin used to monitor the power rail

Source: Hynetek Semiconductor, USB PD Sink Controller
Supporting EPR Mode HUSB238A
Things I've tried:

I tried (without luck due to inexperience) to come up with a circuit based on two MOSFETs and a Zener diode to bypass the DC-DC converter up to 28 V, but couldn't get it to work. I would not like to use a Zener directly to ground, since I want the power rail to remain unaffected.
I tried a simple voltage divider, but this scales the voltages and I would like to maintain accurate unscaled measurements up to the rated voltage of the pin.

EDIT: added the diagram source

user3586056 - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More site rules are in the [tour] & [help].)

How much current is drawn by the vbus pin? If it's sufficiently low, a zener and a large resistor would do what you need.

@Hearth VBUS draws 4.5mA max according to the datasheet. Is that low enough? Are you suggesting to connect them in series between vbus and ground?

Try a low drop-out voltage linear regulator set to the maximum voltage you want to monitor, 28V.  This can be made up with discrete parts, the schematic below shows the idea.  This circuit will force [VOUT_1] to be very close to [VBUS] as [VBUS] rises from about 2V up to 28V, then [VOUT_1] will stay at 28V while [VBUS] rises up to 48V.
Usage: Connect your load at R_LOAD, ie: connect the VBUS pin of the USB-C RECEPTACLE to [VBUS], and connect VBUS pin of the HUSB238A to [VOUT_1].
The simulation below shows that:

When [VBUS] is between 2V and 28V, the difference between [VOUT_1] and [VBUS] is less than 30mV.
The maximum power dissipation in Q2 is 115mW (occurs at VBUS maximum of 48V), but that depends very much on the load.  I have used a 5k resistor as the load (5.6mA at 28V), in your case it may be a constant current of 4.5mA, in which case the power dissipation in Q2 will be higher at lower VBUS.

Design Notes:

Choose Q1 and Q2 to suit the voltage and power stresses, the components shown in the sim are just what was available in the simulation tool (LTspice).
R3 is important to limit power dissipation in Q1.
R2, R5, & C2 stabilise the control loop.
V3, R6, & R1 set the maximum voltage at [VOUT_1].
If an op-amp is not available or not possible (due to no control power supply being present), then make up an equivalent "op-amp" from discrete parts, eg: a diff pair.

Image Below: Schematic

Image Below: DC Plots
[VOUT_1], error voltage, load current, vs [VBUS].


The idea of using an LDO in dropout up to 28 V is great, but there is absolutely no reason to design one when there are hundreds of cheap, ready made options.

@VladimirCravero  This is a rather subtle issue.  The problem is: how well-characterised the "ready-made" options are for this particular use case.  For example: how does it respond to a varying input voltage that starts at 0V then ramps up & exceeds the target regulated voltage.  The important parameters are: what is the overshoot, and what is the difference between Vin and Vout.  Then repeat the test for the power down cycle (Vin at 48V, ramping down to 0V).  I have not yet seen an LDO datasheet that specifies these parameters under this test case, perhaps you can share one?

An N channel JFET in combination with a zener diode can be used here.
To avoid excessive power dissipation and high voltages across the JFET I splitted the voltage and power using two FETs in series.
A small voltage drop across the channel resistance of 300 mV at 5 mA load across each FET remains.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I ultimately decided to go with @Jens solution due to it's simplicity. I simulated various n-channel JFETs such as the 2N4392 (as baseline), CMPF4391, CMPF4392, MMBF4391, MMBFU310, MMBF4393LT1 and the MMBFJ310 along with various combinations of Resistors and Zener Diodes.
Unfortunately my LTSpice crashed before I could save so apologies for the partially cutoff and terribly placed diagram. I have tried to hide irrelevant parts and its mostly just there to show working.
Final Components
I finally landed on the MMBF4391 with 1MOhm Resistors and a Zener Diode with a Breakdown Voltage of 24V. As shown below.
Final Result
This Circuit keeps the Voltage at the VBUS pin within 0.4V-0.6V of the Power Rail Voltage up to around 26V at which point the Voltage starts to flatten out and maxes out at 27.3V@48V. BONUS: The design is very efficient and only leaks about 13uA@48V through the Zener Diode.




Check the behaviour at very fast rising Vin. I was worried about transient gate voltages because there is a capacitance in the zener diode. I tend to use lower values for R1 and R2. I might be wrong, the simulator does not show any issues, verify it.

@Jens So I checked with half a cycle of an AC Vin at Frequencies up to 1 THz and I can't seem to see any such spikes on either of the gates. The response gets more and more sluggish until at 1 THz it can't keep up at all. The power rail would have quite a lot of capacitance and I assume that the outputs of most power banks are slew rate controlled anyways. Thanks for the heads up though. Pls let me know if I am missing something or my simulation is invalid.

That is fine, I thought about Vin rise of >20 V / µs via hard DC power switch.
